# Should I store parsed text? If so, where?

Tags: php, database, parsing, caching

In my application, I chose markdown as the format for some texts.
Obviously, parsing the text takes some time.

The question is, is it worth caching it? And if so, where? Text file or database?

As I see it, I have three options:

- Don't cache. Run the parsing each time the text pulled from the database and displayed.
  (In Symfony2/Twig, I'd just do `{{ text|markdown }}`)
- Have two fields in the database, `content_source` and `content_parsed`. Each time the text is editted, save the parsed code and when requested, simply display the cached code.
- Cache the parsed code as a file. When requested, check if the file exists (if not, parse it and cache it) and display it.

Thoughts?

Comment: personally, i like your second option.  use a trigger.

Comment: What about memcached? That's caching the parsed code, but not as a file. It will retrieve way faster than a file, and it depending on how you code it, it can parse the first time it's requested and then store in the cache. Better than storing the same data twice in the database.

Comment: What about in-memory caches like APC, XCache, or memcache?

Comment: memcached is definitely way faster, lighter on the feet too. Given the options above option 2 (like my answer) is best.. but memcached is definitely way to go if you can.

Comment: @Matthew, thanks for the tip. I never knew this option, glad to learn something new! However, my hosting provider doesn't support it...

Comment: APC might be an interesting option when PHP 5.4 comes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I would store both the source and the parsed content in a database, unless the content gets to be large. Parsing each time is going to be a big scalability problem.

And,it depends on whether you need access to the original content. When I've been in similar situations, I find that we might make changes to how we parse such content, and need to go back and re-parse all of the old content, so its definitely handy to keep the original content around.

Comment: I too think this method is the best but depends on the size. On smaller data with little markdown, I think I'll use option #1 and for big ones (articles etc) #2.

Answer (score 2):

**Option 2:**
Iterate through each "page" parse the MarkDown text, re-save into table as fully parsed. IIRC with a well optimized db, db will be faster than fs open/writes.

You could use cron task to iterate through db nightly or whenever low load is.

Comment: You mean overwriting the source?

Comment: no, just like mike p stated above. having two columns in the table to store both.

Comment: would be great to get a confirmed answer on this if my response answered your question.